# How to handle different output inside expect block

Tags: tcl, expect

Inside expect script, program can give different outputs based on system configuration. I need to handle the output inside expect block for different output and provide input accordingly to proceed with program execution. Is there some way, expect block can be written so that it can find matching patten and proceed and rest other patterns are ignored?

```
Sample script 

    spawn myprogram
     expect {
                        -re "pattern1" {send -- "str1 \r"}
                        -re "pattern2" {send -- "str2 \r"}
                        -re "pattern3" {send -- "str3 \r"}
               }
```

Here based on pattern in the output, action need to be taken.

Comment: Not quite clear to me what your question is. Your code in the post does not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using those double dashes to force the argument to `send` to be interpreted as a string? If so, I think you need spaces after the `--` and before the string:

```
expect {
                -re "pattern1" {send -- "str1 \r"}
                -re "pattern2" {send -- "str2 \r"}
                -re "pattern3" {send -- "str3 \r"}
       }
```

without the space it seems to want to treat everything after the first `-` as one big flag.

To answer your question, yes, this looks like a workable starting point do do what you're asking for: it will watch the output from `testscript` and wait until one of the regular expressions matches, or until the timeout expires (since you are not setting a timeout period, it will default to 10 seconds) or until EOF is received. If one of the regex matches, it will branch into code section that follows the matched expression.

Be careful with the TCL regex syntax, if you are used to PCRE or Vim...

Comment: Sorry there was typo in my previous post. I do have spaces after double dashes. With above code, can expect block match different patterns and send different strings? And for each pattern, I believe it will wait for wait for time as specified in timeout variable.

Comment: @user419534 In that case, you should update your question to include the spaces. As it is, it does not appear to work when I try running it.

Comment: @user419534 I update my answer to (hopefully) answer the question I believe you are asking.

Comment: Thats helpful. Due to some reasons, high value of time out is set to 90 seconds. It would be better to default to 10 seconds or some lower value within expect block. It would be good to have lower value of timeout as 10 seconds and as soon as expect block is completed, it is back to what is set as 90 seconds.